# What is the difference between a parameter and a variable in Dbeaver?

Tags: dbeaver

So my question is what is the difference between a parameter and a variable in Dbeaver?
My second part of the question is how to set / unset a parameter / Variable?
Example 1:

> @set var1 = 1
> @unset var1

here the var1 is set to 1 but cannot be unset with the command @unset

[Example 1:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8VF0i.png)

Example 2: how to set the param1 without the pop-up message?

> select :param1;

[Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtRDP.png)